# Building and copying openjdk across machines

Tags: java

I am currently working on migrating my machines from Oracle JDK to Open JDK.I plan to do this by building OpenJDK 1.8 on my one of my RHEL5 machine (the installable is not available from YUM )and then copying the tarball of OpenJRE 1.8 folder to all other servers (all RHEL5) .
I currently have the multiple standalone instances of an J2EE application running on all these servers.

Please let me know if my method is correct and what all things do I need to ensure to make a smooth transition from Oracle JDK to OpenJDK?

Comment: Please describe what exactly you have done so far. Thank you.

Comment: Well as of now I am just testing my application on OpenJDK 1.6 which was available through Yum on RHEL5. The plan is to go to OpenJDK 1.8 if the testing is all successful.